# Is the group operation on abelian variety flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a field $k$, is it true that sum (i.e. group operation) $m: A\times A \to A$ is a flat map?

Comment: Yes. It's isomorphic to the projection map (consider $A\times A\rightarrow A\times A$ defined by $(g,h)\mapsto (g,gh)$). The projection is flat since it's a base change of the structure map of a variety.